# Chrome based browsers not copying text/html styling

Tags: html, browser, copy-paste, summernote, text-styling

I noticed Chrome-like browsers are not copying HTML formatting. Unlike Firefox.

I used xclip to inspect the clipboard and the targets are different.

**Firefox:**

- TIMESTAMP
- TARGETS
- MULTIPLE
- text/html
- text/_moz_htmlcontext
- text/_moz_htmlinfo
- UTF8_STRING
- COMPOUND_TEXT
- TEXT
- STRING
- text/plain;charset=utf-8
- text/plain
- text/x-moz-url-priv

**Chrome:**

- TIMESTAMP
- TARGETS
- SAVE_TARGETS
- MULTIPLE
- STRING
- UTF8_STRING
- TEXT
- text/plain
- text/plain;charset=utf-8

The problem being, my website uses Summernote editor and users are having trouble getting the content copied to Office apps, is there any way around this?

Comment: Try to create a running example. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question is too open ended

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks for commenting, but I don't see how can I give more information than already given. I told I'm copying formatted content from Summernote text editor in a website and Chrome does not copy with html formatting, but Firefox does. If some specific information is needed, I will do my best to provide.

Comment: For the sake of visualization, here is a video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19lQPSKpv_GkaMKx3MK9JtRXRTX-mHqKl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A video shows you are having a problem. It seems like a problem with Summernotes, have you contacted them? When I try to copy paste from their website, it works fine. You need to be able to come up with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example See https://giphy.com/gifs/Qqp12pZBFvQTpDEGrC which shows it works.